# JacksonFeature breaks JsonIgnoreProperties

Tags: java, jersey, jackson

I have pojo's like these:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SNAPIResponse {

    public String status;
    public String message;
    public int errorCode;

    public ConsumerProfile consumerProfile;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class ConsumerProfile {
        public String accountId;
    }
}
```

and my Jersey client works just fine even though the `ConsumerProfile` responses contain a lot of extra fields.

Then I add a line:

```
client.register(JacksonFeature.class);
```

to my Jersey Client setup. And after that, the ignore's don't work anymore:

```
Unrecognized field "authService" (Class com.xyz..SNAPIResponse$ConsumerProfile), not marked as ignorable
```

Why?

Comment: What version of Jersey are you using? And what version of Jackson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled across this post which helped me get JsonIgnoreProperties working again: http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Beware-of-JacksonFeature-in-Jersey-td7581633.html

I didn't research enough to be 100% sure on the underlying cause of the issue, but it seems registering JacksonFeature.class pulls in an outdated version of a library needed for this.

Doing as suggested in that link worked for me.

Comment: I had forgot about this. But yes, the problem was with Swagger pulling in an ancient version of Jersey or parts of it which causes really random behaviour. I'll accept the answer as the base of it is true: be careful not to use multiple versions of Jersey in your project.